# Eigenvalue bound for sum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The following question seemed innocuous at first, but is escaping me at the moment. Here $\sigma(X)$ denotes the set of eigenvalues of matrix $X$.

> Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfies $\sigma(A)\subset\{\mathfrak{Re}(z)<0\}$, and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ satisfies $\sigma(B)\subset\{\mathfrak{Re}(z)\leq0\}$. Which of the following hold?
>
> 1. $\sigma(A+B)\subset\{\mathfrak{Re}(z)<0\},$
> 2. $\sigma(A+B)\subset\{\mathfrak{Re}(z)\leq0\},$
> 3. Neither 1. or 2.

I realize probably not much could be said in general without some kind of conditions on the eigenspaces of $A,B$, but I cannot think of either a way to prove it nor a counterexample. There probably is an obvious counterexample I am not thinking of...

The case when $A$ is negative definite and $B$ negative semidefinite yields $A+B$ being negative definite, and so 1. holds in this case, however $A,B$ are assumed much more general.

Comment: 3. Choose $A_{12}=B_{21}=0$ and $A_{21}\cdot B_{12}$ "large" to get a counter-example.

Comment: To make it concrete, $B^t=A=[-1,a;0,-1]$ for $|a|>2$.

Comment: @A.S. Got it, thanks